# Отправка письма с помощью mailto

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Не подскажите, как реализовать отправку сообщений с помощью `mailto` с условием, что в параметр `body` вставляется русские буквы? В данный момент вместо тело письма в OutLook вставляются непонятные символы.

Comment: Можете подробнее обьяснить?
Из моих познаний я могу сказать что, mailto это гиперссылка на отправку письма определённому ящику. Тоесть mailto:blabla@mail.ru параметр body? Я думаю о <body> или нет?

Comment: кодировку смотрели?

Comment: тогда автор, сохрани через блокнот свой файл в кодировке UTF-8 и в <head> напиши <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

Answer (score 1):

По идее текст ссылки mailto должен создаваться на основе [RFC 2047](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word), то есть в виде

```
=?charset?encoding?encoded text?=
```

Хотя Outlook все равно не показывает текст латиницей. Можно попробовать прямо кодировать как URL

```
<a href='mailto:to@mail.com?subject=%D2%E5%EC%E0&body=%D2%E5%EA%F1%F2'>ссылка</a>
```

[Примеры для PHP](http://sergey-s-betke.blogs.novgaro.ru/web/wordpress/mail-to-kirillica-ie-outlook-i-php-kak-zhe-ix-pomirit).

Answer (score 0):

Вообщето автор вопроса прав есть возможность задавать и тело и заголовок писма:

```
<a href="mailto:адрес&subject=тема&body=тело письма">Отправить!</a>
```

но чтоб поддерживалась кирилица эту вебстраницу надо сохранить в кодировке utf-8!

Comment: Автор нажмите на галочку около ответа ато ваш вопрос висит в неотвеченных